# Why "/proc/pid/stat" have 2 type?

Tags: stat

When I run command: `cat /proc/$pid/stat`, it returns string like this:

**type 1**:

> 11473 (abc) R 11471 8438 8438 0 -1 4194304 113 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0
>   740394567 13586432 387 18446744073709551615 4194304 4196636
>   140722465367280 140722465367056 4196041 0 0 16781312 0 0 0 0 17 3 0 0
>   0 0 0 6295032 6295624 20967424 140722465373721 140722465373798
>   140722465373798 140722465374123 0

**type 2**:

```
> cpu  127932322 24371 17881916 2752559374 40433812 0 3629274 0 0 0 
> cpu0 32078308 6691 4511623 689457980 9977449 0 62831 0 0 0 
> cpu1 27945507 6745 4406054 689058150 9368678 0 3467446 0 0 0 
> cpu2 34006589 5454 4469269 687604758 9965399 0 45624 0 0 0 
> cpu3 33901916 5480 4494969 686438485 11122284 0 53371 0 0 0 
> intr 10585846379 50 9 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 0 7230416 0 46894546 1845392925 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 
> ctxt 17568581605 btime 1481551477 processes 7067938 
> procs_running 1 
> procs_blocked 0 
> softirq 7511130737 0 2303767815 1777050 1864188938 50494012 0 157806217 1205606999 0 1927489706
```

---

My question is: why the file `/proc/pid/stat` have 2 types. And what's type 2 mean.

Comment: Where do you find the _type 2_ ?

Comment: when I run the code

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    
    cout<<a+b;
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: I khow problem: this is process is finished. So pid not exist.